# A bug with Reactjs OnChange and OnClick Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Recently, I've experienced a weird bug related to ReactJS OnChange and OnClick function. Here's my code

```
  removeHandler(e) {
    var targetValue = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    var answerNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("answer__container");
    for (var answerNode in answerNodes) {
      if (answerNodes.hasOwnProperty(answerNode)) {
        if (answerNode === targetValue) {
          answerNodes[answerNode].remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  onChangeAnswers(e) {
    var answerNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");
    var result = Array.from(answerNodes).map((answer) => {
    return answer.value;
    });
    this.setState({
      answers: result
    });
    console.log(this.state.answers);
  }
```

[The interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRkeQ.png)

Particularly, when I click on remove buttons, the answer will be deleted, but after that, if I click on the answer input and press any key, the answer will disappear again. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're modifiying the DOM directly. This will likely interfere with React's own management of the DOM.

Comment: What @tromgy says is correct. React uses a virtual DOM in which it keeps track of all it's changes. When you edit the DOM yourself React isn't updated about this and will rerender everything that was removed previously.
The way to do this is to keep track of the removed items in a state. Every time the user removes an answer, you add the id (or something unique about the answer) to that state. This way, React will adjust the DOM for you.